# An exception occurred during a WebClient request. device is not ready

Tags: wcf, file-upload

i am working with web service, and created a service and a test client,

i can upload file when using my computer as client and a server, but when i put client on other computer, i am getting error,

> An exception occurred during a WebClient request.

inner exception

> The device is not ready.\r\n"

help me with this pls, i tried googling about it but, i can't find solution.
pls help me understand what is the meaning of this

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the path to the file you are trying to upload does not exist.

However, without posting the code line which causes the exception there's not much anyone can do to help you beyond wild guessing.